# Can't hide articles from the public

Tags: joomla

I have a website done in Joomla 3.3.

I want to hide the acticles from people who are not registered. I have gone into the article and set it to 'registered' and non logged in users can still see them.  I have gone into the menu item (news) and set that to registered but none registed users can still see them.

At a loss so if anyone can help that would be great

http://se24media.net/jps/

Comment: OK I have sorted the permission problem out. What I need is when the user clicks on a news item, I need a login screen, so they can login and read it.

Comment: So is it that you want them to see the title but not the content?